# Wireshark error when display signed 32 bit value as double in protocol tree

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

In my custom dissector, i add gint16 value as

```
gint16 stmp16 = 0;
stmp16 = (gint16)tvb_get_letohs(tvb, suboffset);
proto_tree_add_int_format_value(Din_tree, hf_distanceValue, tvb, suboffset, 2, stmp16, "%lf", stmp16/100.0);
suboffset += 2;
```

It correctly displays the 16 bit signed gint16 value in datagram, whose header field is described as

```
&hf_distanceValue,
{ "Distance Value", "veh.in",
    FT_INT16, BASE_DEC, NULL, 0x0,
    NULL, HFILL }
},
```

However when I try to display 32 bit signed gint32 value, I get error

```
[Dissector bug, protocol CUSTOM: ..\build\epan\proto.c:4128: failed assertion "DISSECTOR_ASSERT_NOT_REACHED"]
```

Value is fetched in same manner using tvb_get_letohl() function,

```
gint32 stmp32 = 0;
stmp32 = (gint32)tvb_get_letohl(tvb, suboffset);
proto_tree_add_int_format_value(Din_tree, hf_speedValue, tvb, suboffset, 4, stmp32, "%lf", stmp32/1000000.0);
suboffset += 4;

&hf_speedValue,
{ "Speed Value", "veh.in",
    FT_INT32, BASE_DEC, NULL, 0x0,
    NULL, HFILL }
},
```

Assertion fails at proto_tree_add_int_format_value() in case value is of type gint32, it works fine in gint16 case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem or not, but you have 2 fields with the same filter name:

```
"Distance Value", "veh.in"
"Speed Value", "veh.in"
```

Normally, you would have something like, `"veh.distance"` and `"veh.speed"`, assuming the abbreviation for your protocol is `"veh"`.  Maybe try changing this first to see if the problem is resolved?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
No, changing filter name doesn't help.